# Chevrolet Corsa doesn't accelerate until I restart the engine

Tags: engine, chevrolet, corsa

It's the 2002 German version of the Corsa, it wasn't made here in America.

It works fine for the first 10 km or so, then it'll suddenly stop accelerating, as if I weren't even pressing the pedal, and I have to restart the machine and it'd work again, for at least other 100-500 meters before failing again. It usually happens when I release the clutch to shift gears, or when I stop accelerating and try to accelerate again.

I've already changed the oil, the fuel and oil filters as well as the sparks, the injection system is clean. I've also checked the pedal and it's ok.

I have since tried with about 5 different people who claim they know how to use a scanner but all of them but one said the scanner didn't find anything, the last one, however, noted that it was receving bad signals from almost all sensors, so he thinks the computer is actually bad. I also asked Scotty Kilmer at his Youtube channel and he also suggested it may be a faulty computer. So I think it may be the issue, wether it can be repaired by "re-flashing" it or it should be replaced I don't know.

What could be causing this?

**Edit:**

Solution here: [Gas pedal not responding](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/gas-pedal-not-responding)

Comment: Sounds like insufficient fuel pressure.

Comment: I would bet the problem lies with the Idle Air Control (IAC) valve, but that is a gut-check guess.

Comment: I've also found some sites that point to the IAC, I haven't heard about the fuel pressure so it's another possibility. I have to double check them.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? If not, I'd recommend hooking this up to a scan tool to get a better sense of what the car is feeling in terms of fuel trims, sensor readings, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have since tried with about 5 different people who claim they know how to use a scanner but all of them but one said the scanner didn't find anything, the last one, however, noted that it was receving bad signals from almost all sensors, so he thinks the computer is actually bad. I also asked Scotty Kilmer at his Youtube channel and he also suggested it may be a faulty computer. So I think it may be the issue, wether it can be repaired by "re-flashing" it or it should be replaced I don't know. I would accept your input on this, thank you.

Comment: @arielnmz I also agree with your assessment that it was caused by a failing ECU; swapping it out may have helped. Did you ever get the issue resolved?

Answer (score 2):

All of the info you've posted seems to point to a failed ECU. In particular:

> It works fine for the first 10 km or so, then it'll suddenly stop accelerating, as if I weren't even pressing the pedal, and I have to restart the machine and it'd work again, for at least other 100-500 meters before failing again.

Could well be explained by a confused ECU intentionally putting the vehicle into [limp mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_throttle_control), and getting reset each time you "reboot" the vehicle. This can also be explained by a faulty TPS except:

> ... the last one, however, noted that it was receving bad signals from almost all sensors ...

Which suggests that the issue is more far-reaching than the TPS or any individual sensors, and really looks like a higher level ECU issue.

As for the lack of error codes showing up on prior scans, with a failing ECU all bets are really off as far as what it reports to you.

The general thing to try here (and ultimate solution if it's really the issue) is to swap out the ECU module with a known good one, perhaps from a salvage yard.