# Car shuts off right after cooling fan turns on

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, temperature, corsa

After several months of looking for issues in my car, I have finally fixed most of them, except for the "catalytic converter" light and the sudden  shut off of the motor.

Today I turned on the car while being completely cool and it turned on perfectly fine. It was running well until it reached about 90° C (the needle was in the exact middle of the display) and as soon as the cooling fan turned on, the car shut off. I then tried to turn it on again but as soon as it turned on, it shut off again. I then tried to accelerate a little bit right after turning it on and it managed to stay running a few more minutes before shutting off itself again.

What could be the problem? I have replaced all the oil, coolant liquid, spark plugs and filters with new ones and this is the only issue that's left. Some people even told me that it was just a matter of "ressetting" the "sensors" with a scanner but what do you think? will this work?

My car is a Chevrolet (not Opel) Corsa 2002 made in Germany and bought in Mexico.

**Edit:**

Solution here: [Gas pedal not responding](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/gas-pedal-not-responding)

Comment: Do you have access to a code scanner so that you can hook it up to the vehicle and tell us what CEL/DTC/error codes there are?

Comment: Does it idle rough every now and then?

Comment: It used to idle very roughly and stalling no matter if warm or cold almost always before doing maintenance, now it just stalls without idling bad or anything.

Comment: @Zaid A friend of my uncle has a scanner (he works at a Chevrolet dealership), but he doesn't come around very often, I'll ask him as soon as possible.

Comment: did you fix the problem? I have same issue. please advise.

Comment: I haven't had any advances on this matter, I should update the question but for the record, my car is missing the tacho-ring and doesn't measure speed and some people have told me that could also contribute to the issue

Answer (score 2):

My money is on a bad earth that's killing the low tension side of the coil when the fan gets power.

Check the wiring security and for breaks in the wiring insulation.  Also check that the earth points look healthy.