# Machine turns off randomly and won't start after staying off for a while

Tags: engine, chevrolet

It all started about a year ago. I had to go to another city and the drive was about an hour long, it went perfectly fine. I left the car parked on the sun for about 2 hours, nothing special, on a region thats about 200 m over the sea level of my own region. The problem appeared when going back. About 5 minutes on the road back, the car suddenly stopped accelerating, as if the gas pedal was completely disconnected. We then proceeded to turn off the machine (after like 10 minutes idle) and turning it on again, and it worked. It worked fine for another 15 minutes before failing again, and this went on until I arrived. Fast forward a few months later and still has the same issue, but this time when the revs drop to about 1000 rpm, the engine idles roughly and the machine turns off, so all I do is keep it revving, but sometimes it just seems to ignore that the pedal is being pushed and drops to 1000 then dies. It went on like this for a few months and it's getting worse. Now it would die at any amount of rpms and also immediately after turning it on again, I don't even have a chance to rev up. I have to leave it off for about 30 minutes before being able to drive for another 5 minutes or so before it dies again, it even happens after turning it on from being cold (like in the morning, 6 am after being off for 12 hours). The catalytic converter light is also on, and it has been like this since even before the first incident.

What do you think? Many "mechanics" have told me it's the TPS sensor, some even say it's the whole computer. Some also say that their scanners didn't find anything. What would be the issue? Is it overheating? Is it the TPS? Is it some electrical issue? I am desperate.

I also have to say that in the past I used to leave the tank almost empty and sometimes it'd dry completely. Now I don't though. I also remember once a truck hit the back of my car and the light of the trunk got stuck in ON and I noticed until when the battery died, about 20 days after. The car is a Chevrolet Corsa 2002.

**Edit:**

Solution here: [Gas pedal not responding](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/gas-pedal-not-responding)

Answer (score 1):

May I ask why you reported this question? You could have easily updated your [previous](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/9866/gas-pedal-not-responding) question with the new details instead of posting the same question again?

---

Anyway as I was saying in my answer, I think it could be an issue with your gas pedal rheostat, if your car uses a DBW system:

I'm betting your Corsa is Drive-By-Wire (DBW), meaning, there isn't a direct connection between you and the throttle. If so, the gas pedal rheostat is probably telling the computer you are pressing it, causing the throttle to go up and in some cases not respond at all. You could possibly test the gas pedal by unplugging it and checking for even/smooth operation by putting an ohmmeter on the leads. You may also try tromping on it a couple of times with the engine off. If you want to send reset the CPU, you need to let it sit for ~30 mins to ensure the residual power is gone. This is the first thing I would have tried as well.

Comment: Thank you, I reposted it to avoid the possible wall-text that I would need to explain all the issues in detail. Like I said, I will check the pedal but I think I am 90% sure it isn't the issue since now it would stall without even pushing it or something, so the issue might not be the pedal's fault.

Answer (score -1):

I would expect TPS/APS for any condition resulting in the gas pedal not functioning as it should.

Comment: Can you explain to the OP (original poster) your acronyms?  Please try and provide as much information as you can in your responses so the information you are giving is valuable across a broad spectrum.  You can take a tour by clicking on this URL to help you better understand how the site works.  Cheers!   http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tour